# how to create folder in C# and give her full-control & full-sharing

Tags: c#, winforms

how to create folder in C# and give her full-control & full-sharing ?

thank's in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229078.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well creating the folder is very easy

```
Directory.CreateDirectory( DIRECTORY );
```

Setting the directory permissions is a bit more difficult.  It's a lot of code to post here so read the MSDN article it's excellent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx

Answer (score -2):

I have created a class which will let you give full access to a directory. Check it here :
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code980-allow-access-control-before-accessing-file-system.aspx

I hope the class will help you.